adding line element between data points spss
Per group (control, intervention) I have two measurements per case (before= left, after= right). Now I want to add a line between the repeated measurements per individual case to display the change per case per group. I have the following syntax:
            * Chart Builder.
              GGRAPH
              /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=Radomization Global_longitudinal_strain Index1 
                MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
              /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
            BEGIN GPL
              SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
              DATA: Radomization=col(source(s), name("Radomization"), unit.category())
              DATA: Global_longitudinal_strain=col(source(s), name("Global_longitudinal_strain"))
              DATA: Index1=col(source(s), name("Index1"), unit.category())
              DATA: id=col(source(s), name("$CASENUM"), unit.category())
              COORD: rect(dim(1,2), cluster(3,0))
              GUIDE: axis(dim(3), label("Radomization"))
              GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label(""))
              GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color), label(""))
              GUIDE: text.title(label("Clustered Boxplot of 10.1|GLS MRI by Radomization by Index1"))
              SCALE: cat(dim(3), include("0", "1"))
              SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
              ELEMENT: point(position(Index1*Global_longitudinal_strain*Radomization), color(Index1))
              ELEMENT: line(position(Index1*Global_longitudinal_strain*Radomization), color(color.black), size(size."2px"), split(id))
            END GPL.

Unfortunately, the code snippet ELEMENT: LINE(position.... etc) does not produce the lines I require. The output I get is attached. Attached also the structure of the data in spss.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/TMtBr1sJ.png)
see above
, see above,
